# Leibniz Notation for the Derivative of a Function

Tags: notation, proof-writing

I am writing a professionally-written proof, and I have come across a bit of an issue regarding how to write the derivative of a function $H(t)$ with respect to $t$.

Is $\frac{dH}{dt}$ an acceptable way of writing this? Otherwise, would I have to write $\frac{dH(t)}{dt}$? I don't really want to say $y=H(t)$, and then write $\frac{dy}{dt}$; that would mean a lot of rewriting.

I couldn't find an answer with a quick google search. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{dH}{dt}$ is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help.

Comment: If you're going to take a lot of derivatives with respect to $t$ and you want some extra room, then you could also make a note that $'=\frac{d}{dt}$ and use $H'(t)$. (Or even use a dot: $\dot{H}(t)$ and $\ddot{H}(t)$.)